# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I know this problem was solving many times but answers i found doesnt work for me.
So my Dataframe columns i operate on look like this:
http://prntscr.com/mu3i86
and i want to create new column like this:

```
df2['Vpip'] = ['No' if (df2['Call_Pre'] == '[]') & (df2['Raise_Pre'] == '[]') else 'Yes' for index, row in df2.iterrows()]
```

I think my parentheses are ok, i'm also using operators & | instead of and, or statement but it still raise me error.
Can u help me fixed it?

Comment: `if (df2['Call_Pre'] == '[]')` this will return a Series of booleans, you need to add `any()` or `all()` or change the logic of your code

Comment: if i add 
    if (df2['Call_Pre'] == '[]').any() or .all() it doesnt work correctly. Can u explain how to change logic of my code?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df2['Vpip'] = np.where((df2['Call_Pre'] == '[]') & (df2['Raise_Pre'] == '[]'),'No','Yes')
```

For `elif` statements , look at [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`

```
df2['Vpip'] = ((df2['Call_Pre'] == '[]') & (df2['Raise_Pre'] == '[]')).map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use the `apply` functionality:

```
def f(row):
    if row['Call_Pre']=='[]' and row['Raise_Pre']=='[]':
        val = 'No'
    else:
        val = 'Yes'
    return val

df2['Vpip'] = df2.apply(f, axis=1)
```